# viewPager does not refreshing instantiateItem

Tags: android, android-viewpager, refresh, notify

In my activity I have a `OnPageChangeListener` and view Pager implemented.

On `onPageSelected`in function I call function name viewPagerHandler, when I have all the logic for single viewPager Page (Buttons, actions depended of current page etc.)

```
 public class ActivityClass extends Activity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, View.OnClickListener{

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.Pager);
            adapter= new 
    ViewPageAdapter(ActivityClass.this,list,imagesList);
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(ActivityClass.this);
    }

    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            this.position=position;
            viewPagerHandler(viewPager.findViewWithTag(position),position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
     public View viewPagerHandler(final View view, final int position){
    //ALL LOGIC BUTTONS ACTIONS ETC.
    view.invalidate();
    return view;
    }
       }
    public class ViewPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

     @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
            final View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.art_work_item, container, false);
           itemView.setTag(position);

container.add(itemView); // edited after suggested
           if(mContext instanceof ActivityClass && position==0) //The page listener in ActivityClass is trigger only when page is changed so i tried to hack it when the viewPager is instantiate for the first time            
return ((ActivityClass) mContext).viewPagerHandler(itemView,position);

            return itemView;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: The logic works perfectly on the first and the last item. For rest of them the view is not refreshing (however its still working, because i have buttons which changing color after clicked, when I click on them and then slide to next item and back to the previous one the color is changed so its trigger)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the line in the instantiateItem() method,

```
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    final View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.art_work_item, container, false);
   itemView.setTag(position);

    container.addView(itemView);

   if(mContext instanceof ActivityClass && position==0) //The page listener in ActivityClass //is trigger only when page is changed so i tried to hack it when the viewPager is //instantiate for the first time
    return ((ActivityClass) mContext).viewPagerHandler(itemView,position);

    return itemView;
}
```

Comment: So should i return container i instantiateItem?

Comment: @Expiredmind no return itemView only but add that to container

Comment: container.addView(itemView);

          return itemView;